# Setting "traffic-split" Parameter for multiple models deployed on vertex ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I want to update the traffic as 50% and 50% for two deployed models on same endpoint(Vertex AI). I am using following command but it is not working.

gcloud ai endpoints update 2003578466645041111 --region=us-central1 --traffic-split=[DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID=4779212008081850368=50,DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID=6143661957686755328=50]  --service-account= ********* --project= **********

In --traffic-split parameter I am passing the IDs of models deployed and percentage of traffic I wanted to set. I tried with many values instead of 50 such as 0.5, .5 etc but its not working. Even I tried removing the word "DEPLOYED_MODEL_ID" and just kept model id and value in the list.

gcloud ai endpoints update 2003578466645041111 --region=us-central1 --traffic-split=[4779212008081850368=50,6143661957686755328=50]  --service-account= ********* --project= **********

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.ai.endpoints.update) argument --traffic-split: Invalid value [50]]